# Javascript, Getting Length of String Held in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
k = [['a'], ['ab'], ['abc']];
alert(k[2].length);
```

The above code fragment returns 1.

How can I get the length of the string, 3 in this case?

Comment: You have an array of arrays... is that really what you want? Why don't you just do `console.log(k[2])` and see what `k[2]` is?

Comment: Maybe a reading a [Javascript Array Tutorial](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays) will help.

Answer (score 8):

The object is not what is expected. Consider:

```
k = [['a'], ['ab'], ['abc']];
a = k[2]    // -> ['abc']
a.length    // -> 1 (length of array)
b = k[2][0] // -> 'abc'
b.length    // -> 3 (length of string)
```

Comment: Yes. Your array seems a bit off but if you can't control it, @pst's answer is correct. Or you may want to flatten it first so that your code works.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `k` is not a normal array containing strings. It contains sub-arrays, which contain the strings. You should declare `k` this way:

```
k = ['a', 'ab', 'abc'];
```

If you do want to use your own declaration, you could do this:

```
alert(k[2][0].length);​
```